# Linked List error in Insertion Function, Segmentation Fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

Compiles fine but when executed I get segmentation fault (core dumped) error. I've tested each function individually and the add function is the only one giving me this error. Add function is supposed to add the value to the head of the linked list. When running the code, values get added to the list correctly and I can display the list, but the error follows shortly after.

```
 //Homework 11
 //Linked List

 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 //Declaring class and Linked List.
 class NumberList
 {
 private:

   struct ListNode
   { 
    double value;
    struct ListNode *next;
   };

   ListNode *head;

 public:

    NumberList()
     { head = NULL;}

    ~NumberList()
     { 
      ListNode *nodePtr;
      ListNode *nextNode;
      nodePtr = head;

      while (nodePtr != NULL)
       {
       nextNode = nodePtr->next;
   delete nodePtr;
   nodePtr = nextNode;
     }
   }

 //Function inserting node at the head.
 void add(double x)
 {
 ListNode *newNode;
 ListNode *nodePtr;
 ListNode *previousNode = NULL;

  newNode = new ListNode;
  newNode->value = x;

 if (!head) 
  {
  head = newNode;
  newNode -> next = NULL;
 }
 else
 {
  nodePtr = head;
  previousNode = NULL;
  }  
  if (previousNode == NULL)
 {   
 head = newNode;
 newNode->next = nodePtr;
 }


 }

 //Function to find matching values.
 bool isMember(double x)
 {
 int pos = 0;
 bool flag = false;

 if (head == NULL)
 {
 cout << "List is Empty" << endl;
 return flag;
 }

ListNode *nodePtr;

 nodePtr = head;

while (nodePtr != NULL)
{
pos++;
if (nodePtr->value == x)
{
  flag = true;
  cout << x << " was found at position " << pos << endl;
}
nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
}

 if (!flag)
  {
    cout << x << " not found in the list." << endl;
  }
 return flag;
 }

 //Function to display linked list values.
 void display() const
 {
   ListNode *nodePtr;

 if (head == NULL)
  {
 cout << "List is empty." << endl;
 return;
  }

  nodePtr = head;

   cout << "The list goes: " << endl;

  while (nodePtr != NULL)
  {
  cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
  nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
  }

   cout << "End" << endl;
  }

  //Function to delete a selected value in the list.
  void deletNodeAll(double x1)
  {
  ListNode *nodePtr;
  ListNode *previousNode;

  if (!head)
  return;

  if (head->value == x1)
  {
  nodePtr = head->next;
  delete head;
  head = nodePtr;
  }
  else
  {
  nodePtr = head;

  while ( nodePtr != NULL && nodePtr->value != x1)
  {
   previousNode = nodePtr;
   nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
  }

   if (nodePtr)
  { 
    previousNode->next = nodePtr->next;
    delete nodePtr;
  }
  }
 }
 };

 int main()
 {
   NumberList Z;

   Z.add(3);
   Z.add(4);
   Z.add(2);
   Z.add(5);
   Z.add(7);
   Z.add(4);
   Z.add(7);
   Z.add(5);
   Z.add(2);
   Z.display();
   Z.isMember(2);
   Z.deletNodeAll(2);
   Z.display();

 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: *Compiles fine* -- This only means that your code has no syntax errors.  It has no bearing on whether the program is logically correct.

Comment: There's a bug in the code. Think it out or use a debugger.

Comment: *When running the code, values get added to the list correctly* -- But you claim that the `add` function is the one giving the trouble.  So how can items be added to the list correctly if `add` has issues?

Comment: Your whole linked list implementation has many many problems, I tried to fix your `add` function but after that you have problem in every other functions, This question is kind of *implement linked list for me*. Please search for c++ linked list, you will get the idea.

Comment: You tell me. When I run the code with just Z.add(2)  in the main i get the error. When I run it again with Z.add(2) and Z.display() I get the list printed out correctly with the segmentation error

Comment: @gabe -- *You tell me.* -- Isn't that what your homework and coursework testing you on?  Whether *you* can find and fix problems with your code by debugging?  Learning how to debug programs is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.

Answer (score 0):

your `add()` method causes segmentation fault because for first node you should update the `head` and `head->next` and `return` but you didn't.

```
if (!head) {
    head = newNode;                            
    newNode -> next = NULL;                           
    return ;/* do this else this again check previousNode == NULL also
                        which is not needed 1st time */  
}
```

Also `deletNodeAll()` deletes only first occurrence of number you are passing, there is a bug in logic,check it yourself.